# Loading GML schema file on QGIS

Tags: qgis, gml, schema-architecture

I am Very New to GML format.

first of all, I have came to the assumption that a schema file will display gml in a particular style as defined by the schema, similar to the way i load a .qml on a shapefile in Qgis.

If this is somewhat correct my problem is;

I can load GML into qgis (as vector layer) and see point and line layers and also data layers with no geometry that refer to said points and lines.

I can view GML text and see the schema location/details.

I also have schema as an .xsd

How do I view a GML as more than just points and lines or an xml doc?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.  I am not a potential answerer of your questions but I suggest that you try to [edit] it back to a single question mark to make the one thing that you are asking clearer.

Comment: XML/GML schema describes the structure of the data. It does not describe the renderings styles. The OGC system for the styles is SLD. You can style the layer with QGIS, save the styles in SLD format and re-use the saved SLD.